# GDB does not stop on break point in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

Created default `Qt Widgets Application` project, placed breakpoints at all `main` func lines but none of them are triggred with both `F5` (Start Debugging Of Startup project) \ F10 (Start and break on main).
The same thing happens with any other project.

code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My kit screenshot (all compilers(including selecting) are auto-detected with Qt and provided with Qt Installer).

[image]

my `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Are you compiling with any optimization flags? If yes, can you try turning them off and then recompiling without any optimizations?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how to check it? The `Compile Output` window provides no information about used command.

Comment: have you set the active build type to "debug"?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no, I did not. Now getting : `-1: error: No rule to make target 'C:/Qt/Static599/5.9.9_Static/lib/libQt5Widgetsd.a', needed by 'debug\untitled1.exe'.  Stop.`.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is a common problem with GUI IDEs that hide everything behind pretty buttons and colorful menus. When something goes wrong, no idea where to look. And all GUI IDEs work differently, so you have to find someone else who uses the same exact version, if you're looking for help. Myself, I stick to the old fashioned Makefile, and invoking builds directly, from the shell prompt. I know exactly what's going on, where all the options are set, and how to change them. There's never any mystery as to what the compiler or the linker is doing.

Comment: I guess you haven't built/installed the Qt debug libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles i have `Debugging Tools for Windows` downloaded and instaled according to Qt Maintance Tool. `Qt creator 4.13.2 Debug Symbols` also

Comment: That's not related to having a debug build of Qt